# Java, regular expressions, String#matches(String)

Tags: java, regex

I'm used to regular expressions from Perl. Does anybody know why this doesn't work (eg. "yea" isn't printed)?

```
if ("zip".matches("ip"))
  System.out.println("yea");
```

Thank you.

Comment: Same gotcha applies to Python and php!

Comment: @JamesAnderson:  At least Python's `search()` method is as easy to use as its `match()` method.  If you want to perform a traditional, non-anchored match in Java, you have to explicitly create a Pattern object, then use it to create a Matcher object so you can call its `find()` method.  There's no equivalent `find()` method in the String class like there is with `matches()`.  (I don't know what you mean about PHP, though; `preg_match()` isn't auto-anchoring.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`matches()` is a complete match; the string has to match the pattern.

```
if ("zip".matches("zip"))
    System.out.println("yea");
```

So you could do:

```
if ("zip".matches(".*ip"))
  System.out.println("yea");
```

For partial matching you can use the complete regex classes and the `find()` method;

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("ip");
Matcher m = p.matcher("zip");
if (m.find())
    System.out.println("yea");
```

Answer (score 1):

The argument to matches() needs to be a fully-formed regular expression rather than just a substring. Either of the following expressions would cause "yea" to be printed:

```
"zip".matches(".*ip.*")

"zip".matches("zip")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
if ("zip".contains("ip"))
```

instead of a RegEx in this case. It's faster, since no RegEx-parser is needed.

Comment: I need some regular expression features which contains() doesn't have.

Answer (score 0):

Try endsWith instead of matches for your "zip" case.

```
"zip".endsWith("ip");
```

If you need regex,

```
"zip".matches(".*ip");
```

[http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.lang/HasSubstr.html](http://Check%20this%20link)